# PyUnit error in PyDev

Tags: python, pydev, python-unittest

I am trying to Use PyUnit within PyDev for the first time. I created a `unittest.py` module. When I did `run as -> Python unit-test`, I got the following error:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

======================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.5.2013052819/pysrc/runfiles.py", line 163, in 
    main()
  File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.5.2013052819/pysrc/runfiles.py", line 77, in main
    pydev_runfiles.main(configuration)
  File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.5.2013052819/pysrc/pydev_runfiles.py", line 761, in main
    PydevTestRunner(configuration).run_tests()
  File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.5.2013052819/pysrc/pydev_runfiles.py", line 747, in run_tests
    runner.run(test_suite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/runner.py", line 158, in run
    result.printErrors()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/runner.py", line 108, in printErrors
    self.printErrorList('ERROR', self.errors)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/runner.py", line 114, in printErrorList
    self.stream.writeln("%s: %s" % (flavour,self.getDescription(test)))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/runner.py", line 46, in getDescription
    return '\n'.join((str(test), doc_first_line))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 1060, in __str__
    self._testFunc.__name__)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

My unit test is just the PyDev-generated default:

```
import unittest


class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        pass


    def tearDown(self):
        pass


    def testName(self):
        pass
        print "hello test"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

I expected it to print `hello test`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I realized your problem, after having a similar issue for several minutes. You need to rename your file. Name it anything other than unittest.py. This causes the compiler to confuse between your module and the unittest module that you are importing.

Second, even after you change the name of your file, you may run into the same error. That is caused by the unittest.pyc file not being removed from your project. Rename the file, delete the previously generated unittest.pyc file, and the test should run just fine.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed to know! It would have taken me a really long time to figure that out. I wish I had the rep points to bump your answer. I hope other people will do that for me!